# Check if a form field value is present in a given list of data

Tags: javascript

I have a form, and when it's submitted some Javascript runs and performs a couple of tasks. One task that I need to add is checking the value entered into one of the fields to make sure that that value matches at least one value in a given list.

specifically I need to make sure that a user has entered a postal code that is listed as an area that is covered. I have an excel file with thousands of postal codes and am trying to figure out the best/most efficient way of performing the check.

Could I export the postal codes to a txt file and have Javascript look through that to find a match?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: **too broad** _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is create a CSV file: a file with a ZIP code for each row. And a Javascript code that finds the matching in this file.

It is very easy export this data form Excel to a simple text file (or more text file).